# Why is dollar sign in url rewrite not working?

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

Looking at the question [How do I use web.config to redirect to a query string on Windows Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181429/how-do-i-use-web-config-to-redirect-to-a-query-string-on-windows-server-2008-r2)

This is what I have in web.config:

```
<rule name="Rewrite Rule 21" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^page/&#36;1-per-year$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/1-dollar-per-year" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I get a 404 error every time. Even tried `%24`

How can I get this to work? All of my other redirects are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your regexp you just need to escape dollar sign (\$). Your rule should be:

```
<rule name="Rewrite Rule 21" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^page/\$1-per-year$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/1-dollar-per-year" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```